# How much does Town Hall Level 9+ reduce the loot from opponents?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I noticed that the game tells me that upgrading my Town Hall to level 9 will reduce the loot obtainable from TH level 8 and below.  How much is this decrease?

[image]

Comment: Is this still the case or has it been changed to 20% loot available no matter town hall level?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to find out there is a loot multiplier for when you attack someone in matchmaking.  The loot gained is affected by the Town Hall difference between the attacker and the defender.

> Players get increased loot for attacking Town Halls of a higher level,
>   and reduced loot for attacking Town Halls of a lower level.

[image]

Example: If an attacker has a Town Hall level 9 and a defender has a Town Hall level 8, only 90% if his total available resources is considered lootable.

*Note: Matchmaking isn't set up by Town Hall levels, it is based on total trophies the opponent has.*

[Source](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Town_Hall)

Comment: yes, that is why rushing your townhall is not such a great idea

Answer (score 2):

That's 90% of the 20% that everyone has available. Its always 20% available, then the multiplier comes into effect.